Trying to create MULTIPLE dynamic chart titles
I'm using the following Apps-script, google extension:
/**
* Function to automatically change chart title
*/
function changeChartTitle() {

// get the chart
// assumes only one chart, adjust the index [0] if needed
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheet1');
const chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];

// get the chart title from the cell
const newTitle = sheet.getRange('a1').getValue();

// update the chart title to the new title
const chartBuilder = chart.modify();
chartBuilder.setOption('title', newTitle);
const updatedChart = chartBuilder.build();
sheet.updateChart(updatedChart);
}

My question is I’ve got multiple charts on the same sheet, would I be able to create dynamic titles for each chart on the same sheet? Right now I'm limited to 1 chart title and don't know how if I can revise to use it in multiple chart titles within th the same sheet.
I have raw data on one sheet, a pivot table that funnels the data into 6 stocks on another sheet, then on my 3rd sheet raw data of weekly closing prices over 2 yrs, the on my 4th sheet I’m displaying each stocks 2 yr chart.
I would like to show each chart stacked on one another with a dynamic chart title.
Thanks in advance.
I'm a novice at this and have no idea.

Next time, please use the code sample format for your script.

Also, please provide a minimal reproducible example like markdown tables containing your sample input data.

Just loop through the array that getCharts() returns

You want to change chart titles for all the charts on a given sheet. But your existing script only changes the title for one chart.
The script can assign titles to multiple charts.
Right now I'm limited to 1 chart title You are limited to one chart title because const chart = sheet.getCharts()[0]; selects one chart. As @Cooper suggests, you need to loop through the charts and change the title each time.
The key differences are:

const charts = sheet.getCharts() - get ALL the charts (in a 1D array)
const newTitles = sheet.getRange('a2:A4').getValues() - get title details (in a 2D array)
for (var i=0;i<charts.length;i++){ - creates a loop for the charts which contains the chart builder code.
var chart = charts[i] - select each chart as the loop progresses
chartBuilder.setOption('title', newTitles[i][0]); - select the title from the 2D array


/**
* Function to automatically change chart titles
*/
function changeAllChartTitles() {

  // get the charts
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const charts = sheet.getCharts()
  // get chart titles (in same order as chart index)
  // as many titles as there are charts
  const newTitles = sheet.getRange('a2:A4').getValues()
  // or you could create an array containing the chart titles

  // loop through the charts and 
  // update the chart title to the new title
  for (var i=0;i<charts.length;i++){
    var chart = charts[i]
    var chartBuilder = chart.modify();
    chartBuilder.setOption('title', newTitles[i][0]);
    var updatedChart = chartBuilder.build();
    sheet.updateChart(updatedChart);
  }
}


SAMPLE - after


SAMPLE - before

